# French chapter numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering, conditionals, chapters, counters

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`impnattypo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo)

French typography recommends that chapters be numbered in uppercase roman numbers, except for chapter 1 which should be called "Chapitre premier", so it should be:

- Chapitre premier
- Chapitre II
- Chapitre III
- etc.

Trying to implement that, I've come up so far with:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}                                                             
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%                                                    
  \ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=1}{premier}{\Roman{chapter}}                      
}
```

However, when compiling with this, I get:

```
! Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.1 \chapter{\`A la recherche de la r\'eponse}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: This chapter numbering messes up the table of contents big time!

Comment: Right. I've checked a few books though, and it is indeed in use.

Comment: Note that French typography recommends to put the ToC at the end of the book (that's right, even after the index actually), so hardly anyone gets to see it anyway.

Comment: My solution would be "Don't use such a crazy typesetting convention"! Those crazy French...

Comment: @Seamus: Haha! I wish French typography was easier...

Comment: @Raphink any people who speak a language that insists "ninety" should be said "four-twenty-ten" should probably not be trusted to come up with sane typographical conventions...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a solution using `\ifnum`, without `ifthen`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%                                                    
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=1
    premier%
  \else
    \Roman{chapter}%
  \fi
} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way do to it without affecting the ToC, so that only the chapter headings is modified, but the arabic number is still used elsewhere?

Comment: @Raphink: in that case don't redefine `\thechapter`, customize the chapter headings instead, for example using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Comment: If I were to do a CTAN package to make it easier for all thriving French TeXnicians, which solution would you recommend?

Comment: @Raphink: Some classes implement chapter headings differently, so it might be hard to produce a general headings-only solution. You could redefine `\@makechapterhead` though it's not guaranteed that classes other than the base classes use it.

Answer (score 6):

I guess that `ifthen` somehow fails at proper expansion. Use [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) instead.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}                                                          
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%                                            
  \ifnumequal{\value{chapter}}{1}{premier}{\Roman{chapter}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\blindtext

\chapter{bar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```